# Just installed the IBM Blockchain extension but running into an issue starting "1 Org Local Fabric"

Tags: ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

Localhost info:
OS: Windows 7
IBM Blockchain Platform: 1.0.31

Just installed the IBM Blockchain extension but running into an issue starting "1 Org Local Fabric". I'm following the tutorial on 'A3'. When I right click -> 'Start' on "1 Org Local Fabric", I got the log messages below. I'm new to all this and hoping someone could help me overcome this issue.

```
------------------------------- [START LOG] ------------------------------- 

[6/2/2020 5:00:05 PM] [INFO] startFabricRuntime

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>rem

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>rem Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved 

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>rem

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>rem SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>rem

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>docker

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO]  run --rm -v "C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric":/network -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network host ibmblockchain/vscode-prereqs:0.0.16 ansible-playbook /network/playbook.yml 

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /network.

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] See 'docker run --help'.

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\test\\.fabric-vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric>if 125 NEQ 0 

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [INFO] (exit /b 125 ) 

[6/2/2020 5:00:33 PM] [ERROR] Failed to start 1 Org Local Fabric: Error: Failed to execute command "cmd" with  arguments "/c, generate.cmd" return code 125


------------------------------- [END LOG] -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 isn't supported - only Windows 10 Pro & Enterprise.

Please see [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension#dependency-installation) for information on required dependencies.